# can I add an ad with markdown in django?

Tags: django, markdown

I am using django-markdown-deux and I would like to add ads by doing something like [ad_x] and then finding it via regexso I don't have to add a bunch of html to all my pages manually.

In markdown deux, they have a link_patterns setting which does the same thing, but it is pre-made to only turn the matched expression into a link and not whatever I want to put in it.

Is there an easy way to do this?